# Netbeans: Unable to create new Java Application

Tags: java, netbeans

Since I remember I've always been able to create a Java Application in Netbeans doing File->New Project->Java->Java Application. Today I turned on my computer and the Java field "disappeared". The only thing I did in the past days is to begin working with Java FX. I checked the Plugins and everything seems fine.
[image: Project Creation]

[image: Plugins]

I did some quick research but couldn't find anything similar.
Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: I assume all your existing java projects still work?

Comment: yes all of them work as intended

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of talk about deleting the user settings eg [Project category "Java" missing SOLVED](https://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic20602.html) and [Missing the Java category in New Project - Help Is Appreciated!](http://www.java-forums.org/netbeans/63338-missing-java-category-new-project-help-appreciated.html) (<--talk about massive overreaction)

Comment: `Thanks for nothing you inactive junkies - I ain't ever coming back.` ahah that made my day :). Thanks for the link tho, I'll try deleting the userdir.